# Weird behavior checking if np.nan is in list from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

It seems that checking if np.nan is in a list after pulling the list from a pandas dataframe does not correctly return True as expected. I have an example below to demonstrate:

```py
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

basic_list = [0.0, nan, 1.0, 2.0]
nan_in_list = (nan in basic_list)
print(f"Is nan in {basic_list}? {nan_in_list}")

df = pd.DataFrame({'test_list': basic_list})
pandas_list = df['test_list'].to_list()
nan_in_pandas_list = (nan in pandas_list)
print(f"Is nan in {pandas_list}? {nan_in_pandas_list}")
```

I would expect the output of this program to be:

```
Is nan in [0.0, nan, 1.0, 2.0]? True
Is nan in [0.0, nan, 1.0, 2.0]? True
```

But instead it is

```
Is nan in [0.0, nan, 1.0, 2.0]? True
Is nan in [0.0, nan, 1.0, 2.0]? False
```

What is the cause of this odd behavior or am I missing something?

Edit:
Adding on to this, if I run the code:

```
for item in pandas_list:
    print(type(item))
    print(item)
```

it has the exact same output as if I were to swap `pandas_list` with `basic_list`. However `pandas_list == basic_list` evaluates to False.

Comment: `in` uses `==` to test if the value is in the list. `nan == nan` is false, so it doesn't find it. You have to use `math.isnan()` to test for NaN.

Comment: or `nan_in_pandas_list = any(nan for i in pandas_list)`

Comment: @Barmar Ahh I didn't know that. That makes sense. But then why does `nan in [0.0, nan, 1.0, 2.0]` evaluate to True.

Comment: Sorry, misread your examples. I think there's a difference between a numpy NaN and a pandas NaN.

Comment: @Barmar no, the issue is that `in` first checks `is` (as an optimization), so that is why `nan = float('nan'); data = [nan]; print(nan in data)` will print `True`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Unless there's a dup, that would be the beginning of a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`pandas` is using different `nan` object than `np.nan` and `in` operator for `list` checks if the object is the same.

---

The `in` operator invokes `__contains__` magic method of list, [here is source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61e818409567ce452af60605937cdedf582f6293/Objects/listobject.c#L443):

```c
static int
list_contains(PyListObject *a, PyObject *el)
{
    PyObject *item;
    Py_ssize_t i;
    int cmp;

    for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i) {
        item = PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i);
        Py_INCREF(item);
        cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(item, el, Py_EQ);
        Py_DECREF(item);
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

You see there is [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool) called which states:

> If o1 and o2 are the same object, PyObject_RichCompareBool() will
> always return 1 for Py_EQ and 0 for Py_NE.

So:

```py
basic_list = [0.0, nan, 1.0, 2.0]
for v in basic_list:
    print(v == nan, v is nan)

print(nan in basic_list)
```

Prints:

```
False False
False True
False False
False False
True
```

And:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"test_list": basic_list})
pandas_list = df["test_list"].to_list()

for v in pandas_list:
    print(v == nan, v is nan)

print(nan in pandas_list)
```

Prints:

```
False False
False False
False False
False False
False
```

Evidently, `pandas` is using different `nan` object.

Answer (score 1):

So, for the built-in `list` type, `in` checks containment using `is` first (as an optimization). From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or
> collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

(note, of course, the above isn't how this is actually implemented! dicts and sets, for example, are using hash-based approaches to check containment, so they will be average case O(1) instead of O(n))

This is an optimization that the runtime uses because *well behaved* types should always respect the logical implication that "if x is y, the x == y". But *this happens to not be true with the very strange value of `float('nan')`.

Since you are using the *same object* to check, the one that `numpy` plops into the main namespace for you (it is literally doing something like `nan = float('nan')`) it turns out this will be true when you construct a list using that object.

We can reproduce this behavior like this:

```
nan = float('nan')
data = [1, nan, 3]
print(nan in data) # True
print(float('nan') in data) # False
```